# Enabling input field to enter value

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

I have an input field on a form that is readonly disabled and want to enable it.

Case: In the code there is a field which accepts 14 digit number. This number is divided into two parts:

1. First part is Default value (`53600184`) and it is `readonly disabled`.
2. Second part is 6 digit value which is enterable. Please see below code:

   `<input type="hidden" NAME="Default" value="53600184" size="8" maxlength="8">
   <input type="text" value="53600184" size="8" maxlength="8" readonly disabled>
   <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="Enterable" VALUE="" SIZE="6" MAXLENGTH="6">`

Now, I want to change `readonly disabled field to enterable in the way that it should allow me to change only the last digit like:

e.g.

1. 53600185
2. 53600186 etc

Is this possible?

Comment: Actually, it is a coldfusion application. I found this code bug  when I used firebug extension in firefox to go through cfm file.

Comment: FYI, this seems to pertain to "javascript" not "java". Tags updated.

Comment: This is just mark-up, and the issue is entirely clientside. What's it got to do with ColdFusion?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a separate input field for the last digit.

```
<input name="readOnlyPart" readonly="yes" value="5360018" />
<input name="lastDigit" maxlength="1" value="4" />
```

Then when you process the form, concatenate the two form field values.

**Edit starts here**

If there are only three possible values, this is even simpler:

```
<select name="someNumber">
<option value = "53600184">display text for this option</option>
<option value = "53600185">display text for this option</option>
<option value = "53600186">display text for this option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is it possible to give value as 4 or 5?

Comment: The last digit can be anything

Comment: @Userx you could make that value a select box instead of a text input. Then you could only allow the values 4 or 5. Either way, you still need to validate the input on the server.